# Pie Chart for Data on Different Things with HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using [HichChart](http://www.highcharts.com/)'s pie charts for showing data about about the report of different students -- this chart is divided into sections:

- Positive data.
- Negative data.

I've got it working perfectly for a single student, but a problem arises when I am inside someone's positive areaand then I clcik on another student - the pie chart uses the colours of the positive side (and I do not recall telling it to do this). the main problem is that when i am in drilled stage i have to go back otherwise it loads the different data with different colors .

Here is my code:

```
<div id="ChartContainer" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function(){
    HighCharts.chart('ChartContainer', {
        chat: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Positive: 426 / Need Work: 28'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size: 250,
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + '%';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{
                name: 'Positive',
                y: 4,
                color:'#00ff00',
                drilldown: 'Posit'
            }, {
                name: 'Negative',
                y: 4,
                color: '#ff7a0f',
                drilldown: 'Negit'
            }, ]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                color: 'green',
                id: 'Posit',
                data: [
                    {name:'one', y:4, color: 'Red'},
                    ['two', 2],
                    ['three', 1],
                    ['four', 2],
                    ['five', 1]
                ]

            }, {
                 color: 'Blue',
                id: 'Negit',
                data: [
                    {name:'one', y:4, color: 'Blue'},
                    ['Seven', 4],
                    ['Eight', 2],
                    ['Nine', 3]
                ]

            }

           ]
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: as i understood you want same color for all positive drilldown section green wright?

Comment: I think you have to declare it for each data element in drilldown series as you do in first  {name:'one', y:4, color: 'Red'}

Comment: No... when i am in drilldown stage and load the chart for another one .. it still shows me in the drilled stage with new data

Comment: May be its because of this line  {name:'one', y:4, color: 'Red'}
once remove or change it like other and try..

Comment: nope.. its not working

Comment: Can't you set the color explicitly for each point?

Comment: @morganfree i can't bcoz the data is totaly unknown for each student ...

Comment: You can prepare the array with colors and then just associate the color with each point, so the colors will not be repeated. http://jsfiddle.net/qbzL8cyd/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are forget to include https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js
in script tag.It should be refer in the index.html. you value is converted to percentage. that's y it shows the different value.

Comment: nope , i resolved this .. this was arising when i use this in nested script .

Comment: I reformated your code. please refer the following jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/qbzL8cyd

Comment: if you have a any doubt, feel free ask me